What is the pole on the right side of the A4E Early?
I was playing War Thunder, and I wondered: what is the pole on the right side of the A4-E Early (picture source)?


Screencap of what you're seeing? But assuming you're talking about a Navy A-4, that is likely the air refueling probe.

I can only guess the refueling probe is correct, but who knows that OP means for sure: https://wiki.warthunder.com/A-4E_Early#Media

Similar to What is this nose projection on the Tupolev Tu-95?, or What is this tube along the right side of a Blue Angel? and many other.

This pic captured from:
https://wiki.warthunder.com/A-4E_Early_(M)_(Israel)

The "pole" on the right side is the air refueling probe.
